Failed Attempt to deploy to heroku, Running latest version of Rails 8.0 ruby 3.2.2. I am beginner so I am not sure what to do
Ran the push command to deploy to heroku, i keep getting a fail message. i tried reading up on the problem and it seems that the ruby version is not specified. i read on heroku that it assumes a default version for version 2.5 and above so it this could not be a problem after all. i am thinking the the gem pg is the problem because of heroku requirements. anyways, any input is appreciate as i have gave my best to resolve this issue but so far unable to do so.
git push heroku HEAD:master      
Enumerating objects: 117, done.
Counting objects: 100% (117/117), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (104/104), done.
Writing objects: 100% (117/117), 46.53 KiB | 6.65 MiB/s, done.
Total 117 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Updated 103 paths from ad68afd
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-24 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.5.6
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        No ruby version specified in the Gemfile.lock
remote:        
remote:        We could not determine the version of Ruby from your Gemfile.lock.
remote:        
remote:          $ bundle platform --ruby
remote:          No ruby version specified
remote:        
remote:          $ bundle -v
remote:          Bundler version 2.5.6
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Ensure the above command outputs the version of Ruby you expect. If you have a ruby version specified in your Gemfile, you can update the Gemfile.lock by running the following command:
remote:        
remote:          $ bundle update --ruby
remote:        
remote:        Make sure you commit the results to git before attempting to deploy again:
remote:        
remote:          $ git add Gemfile.lock
remote:          $ git commit -m "update ruby version"
remote: 
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.1.6
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.5.6
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        activesupport-8.0.0 requires ruby version >= 3.2.0, which is incompatible with
remote:        the current version, 3.1.6
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        activesupport-8.0.0 requires ruby version >= 3.2.0, which is incompatible with
remote:        the current version, 3.1.6
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 8414643d8039fe52725693b0806b9fc259324153
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 8414643d8039fe52725693b0806b9fc259324153
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to radiant-hamlet-84739.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/radiant-hamlet-84739.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/radiant-hamlet-84739.git'

i tried to look up other posts on StackOverflow and google but I have been out of luck.
would someone please take a look at my error and suggest a solution. i would appreciate it.
here is my gemfile:
[# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3" 
# Use the Puma web server \[https://github.com/puma/puma\]
gem "puma", ">= 5.0"
# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps \[https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails\]
gem "importmap-rails"
# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator \[https://turbo.hotwired.dev\]
gem "turbo-rails"
# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework \[https://stimulus.hotwired.dev\]
gem "stimulus-rails"
# Build JSON APIs with ease \[https://github.com/rails/jbuilder\]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password \[https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword\]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i\[ windows jruby \]

# Use the database-backed adapters for Rails.cache, Active Job, and Action Cable
gem "solid_cache"
gem "solid_queue"
gem "solid_cable"

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Deploy this application anywhere as a Docker container \[https://kamal-deploy.org\]
gem "kamal", require: false

# Add HTTP asset caching/compression and X-Sendfile acceleration to Puma \[https://github.com/basecamp/thruster/\]
gem "thruster", require: false

# Use Active Storage variants \[https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images\]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i\[ mri windows \], require: "debug/prelude"

  # Static analysis for security vulnerabilities \[https://brakemanscanner.org/\]
  gem "brakeman", require: false

  # Omakase Ruby styling \[https://github.com/rails/rubocop-rails-omakase/\]
  gem "rubocop-rails-omakase", require: false
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages \[https://github.com/rails/web-console\]
  gem "web-console"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing \[https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing\]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end

group :production do 
  gem 'pg', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.9'
end][1]

Best,enter code here


the current version, 3.1.6 — you need to set the ruby Version to 3.2.2


when i run ruby -v on my command line, it says its 3.2.2

That's the ruby version on your local shell. The logs clearly say Using Ruby version: ruby-3.1.6. If you want to check the version on heroku you would have to run heroku run ruby -v.

You need to remove the sqlite3 gem from your gemfile or at least move it from the default group (the top level of the Gemfile) into group :development, :test. Installing the SQLite gem fails on Heroku because the libraries that the gem depends on are not present by design.

SQLite runs in memory, and backs up its data store in files on disk. While this strategy works well for development, Heroku’s Cedar stack has an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it, and you can read from it, but the contents will be cleared periodically. If you were to use SQLite on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least once every 24 hours.
Even if Heroku’s disks were persistent running SQLite would still not be a good fit. Since SQLite does not run as a service, each dyno would run a separate running copy. Each of these copies need their own disk backed store. This would mean that each dyno powering your app would have a different set of data since the disks are not synchronized.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Also make sure that you have reconfigured the database adapter in config/database.yml.
While you could use Postgres in production and SQLite in development/testing I do not recommend this approach as there are many differences between them that ActiveRecord cannot fully abstract away. You do not want to find out about them by blowing up your production environment. See https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity.
In addition you'll need to reconfigure solid_cache, solid_queue and solid_cable or ditch them and use Redis/memcached. All three are new in Rails 8 so it will take a while for the guides to catch up.
Rails 8 also requires a minimum of Ruby 3.2 so set your Ruby version.
This answer also isn't really an exhastive list of what you'll need to fix to get your application to run on Heroku. Just the obvious known problems with your code. Rails 8 was just released and the new defaults are at odds with platforms like Heroku so it will likely require quite a bit of work on your part to get it to deploy.

In my very subjective opinion Heroku might not be the best choice in 2024 if you just want to toss something up quickly and have the smoothest possible expecience.

I am following a tutorial and the instructor uses the heroku in the tutorial. by the way i removed the sqlite3 from my gemfile and reconfigured the config/database.hml file but still no luck.

The tutorial you're following may be outdated. Heroku has phased out its free offerings so I would just skip the parts that are related to deployment and look at the other SAAS platforms later when you actually need to deploy an application.

Thank you. Will do. That is in fact the case
